# Is it possible to store things in a MVC Controller?

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

This might be a stupid question and I am sceptics of this would even be a good practices, but I would like to know for sure, so here goes.

If the HomeController have a list as a field, and one user add to it, would that user get the list back with something in it or would it be empty?

And what about when there is more users how would that (not?) work? Whould they have their own list?

I am asking because I know how to persist small things on client and bigger things in DB but I would like to know if I have a "Server" options, where I can store something in the Controller in MVC.

```
public List<int> Ids { get; set; }

public HomeController()
{
    Ids = new List<int>();
}

public ContentResult AddToIds(int id)
{
    Ids.Add(id);
    return Content("Added");
}

public ContentResult GetIds()
{
    return Content(Ids.Count.ToString());
}
```

Comment: I believe unless you declarate List<int> Ids static, this wouldn't work.  Why not use HttpCache object with sliding expiration or create a class and keep one instance alive all the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The controller is instantiated and disposed for each request, so anything you set on it will not survive the next request.

Comment: Thanks alot man. That's why I have never seen such pratices before. I had a suspicion but no final argument.

Comment: For what it's worth, you can employ `Session` or `TempData` to persist data between requests. They both use sessions; the only difference is that `TempData` only survives one further request unless you reset it, whereas data in `Session` persists for the life of the session. However, the use of either should be avoided as much as possible. Treat them as last resorts when you really truly need to persist something that should not simply just be saved in a database instead.

Comment: I don't like Session and TempData then.
I need the list in my strongly typed partial view for a table.
I think my best options then is to maintain (add/remove) it with an ajax request to the server where i add the id's and put the new list in the view model.

Answer (score 1):

As an addition to Chris's answer, MVC is designed to be relatively stateless. That's partly why the controllers are instantiated and disposed as they are.

It sounds like your application may need a slight re-think if you have a need of this. You *could* persist your list in a number of ways that include session and the `static` modifier, but you shouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET creates an instance of HomeController for each request.  So the code you posted the list will only live for the lifetime of the request. If you make the list static, like this:

```
public static List<int> Ids { get; set; }
```

It will live for the lifetime of the application.  An IISRESET or reboot will empty the list unexpectedly.  Also, if your application is running on multiple machines (ie an Azure Website with multiple instances), then items added on one instance will not be visible on another instance.

Often, if you find yourself keeping lots of state in this way, it means you may be going about things the wrong way.  Cache, Session, Db, or some other persistence strategy is how you would typically keep state.

Comment: I have spent the whole day thinking about others solutions and didn't come up with a good one so now I needed to rule this "solution" out. :)

Comment: It should be mentioned that the biggest problem with statics is cross-request contamination. A static not only survives between multiple requests by one user, but also requests by *all* users. You can get yourself into big trouble quick.